# Experiences with Javeline / Ajax.org javascript framework?

Tags: javascript, ajax, frameworks

I've been looking for javascript frameworks to build a spreadsheet-like app and found [Ajax.org](http://www.ajax.org/).
Does anybody have experience with it? With that name is hopeless to try to google for it.

I'm curious about how it compares to [Sproutcore](http://www.sproutcore.com/) or [Cappuccino](http://cappuccino.org/).

Thanks!

jbar

Comment: Let me put it this way. Their main-page isn't working with opera - completely messed up and a nasty javascript stacktrace in the errorlog. So maybe search for a framework where at least their mainpage works in every browser

Comment: Good idea jitter :)  Thanks for the Opera datapoint

Comment: I've been looking at it recently and about half the examples have JavaScript errors in IE7.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a late response, but I recently started using this framework. I think it's great and has the potential to be better than a ExtJS or YUI. The mark-up is much cleaner and clear-cut. However, support is hard to find. I have been digging through the source code to learn what to do.

Their 3.0 product is where you want to be, but it's in beta. Once it comes out of beta, I'm guessing the docs will follow.

Also, I think the focus is on ajax.org, rather than Javeline.